# How do YOU handle bad parameters in functions?

Tags: syntax

Let's say you have some function that has one int parameter that can be good or bad. Let's say that it's bad when it's less than 5. And if it's bad you should get out of function. I think you already made up that function in your mind. Now tell me which of these functions is what you would've written.

```
1.
void abc(int a)
{
    if (a < 5) return;
    //...
}

2.
void abc(int a)
{
    if (a >= 5)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This may sound like a really stupid question. But I often have hard time deciding between these two lol.

Comment: I don't see any relation to functional programming.

Comment: Both options have a place and choosing between them is a matter of opinion. Asking us to complete an off-site survey is off-topic and perilously close to spam.

Comment: @MikeW that's why I created a throwaway

Comment: Using `return;` inside a non-void function is a compile-time error in the vast majority of statically typed languages. Likewise having a control path that does not return a value is either a compile-time error or a run-time error/undefined behavior when that path is reached. Hence both of the options you suggested are errors in most languages and thus neither option should be chosen.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I prefer the first way:

```
if a < 5 
    // return error or throw exception
```

To me it looks like some kind of "guard". Also you should handle this "bad" variable somehow (return error, throw exception) and it will be harder to follow if this is in some `else` block somewhere in the function.